# What is the refractive index of an electron?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, electrons, scattering, photoelectric-effect

Consider a free electron or electron bunch, would it have a corresponding refractive index?  At low or high energies, the effects are obviously much different.  I am curious to know (I haven't found) if anyone has worked this out in detail starting from fundamental principles. Thanks.

Comment: The refractive index is a collective property so a single electron does not have a refractive index.

Comment: The refractive index of a gas of electrons is "well known".   There are many discussions on the web.  The search terms would be *plasma* and *refractive index*.

Comment: @JohnRennie So an electron bunch would?

Comment: @garyp however a plasma is quite different from a collection of free electrons; in the latter there is no screening of any electrostatic potentials from e.g. positive ions

Comment: Indeed as said above the refractive index is a collection of properties and does not really apply to microscopic entities.